# Slow watchos debug install on real device

Tags: xcode, debugging, apple-watch

Every time I make a small change it takes me more than 4 minutes to install an application from Xcode to my apple watch.Copying swift librairies for instance takes forever

Is there a special set up to fasten the process ? Right now I only have my phone plugged to my computer, I guess that the app gets installed on the watch with bluetooth which is quite slow

Comment: Suffering as well. Apple doesn't care about watchOS devs

Answer (score 2):

Also, have you put a charger on the watch while trying to debug?  This usually speeds things up.  My theory is that it goes in to a lower power mode when not on a charger and possibly, as you note, does everything over bluetooth.  There may be something that slows this down for power saving, as bluetooth to the watch can be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a cache issue, so you could try to either use the command-shift-k key combo to clean your build or manually delete the cache through Finder on your mac(if that's what you're using). This incidentally could help clear out some "system storage", which is imo a big issue with osx.

Another thing to keep an eye out for is what you're building for. In xcode if you click on Product and hover over "Build For", you get three options: "Running", "Testing" and "Profiling". On a random project i opened, the "Running" option took half as long as "Testing" to build and send to my device.

It could also be a slow computer.

Comment: Yes testing is even longer that building, and I tried cleaning the build folder : It does not help the bluetooth is still quite slow, since the standard Swift libraries are not included in the devices, it has to been copied everytime... Is there another way to debug on a watch (through wifi for instance ? )
And no, my computer is new macbook pro with SSD, I don't think it's the problem